# What is the best move in algebraic chess notation?

Tags: analysis, tactics, puzzles

I can't fine the best move with algebraic chess notation.

```
[Title "White to Move"]
[FEN "r3n1rk/q3NQ1p/p2pbP2/1p4p1/1P1pP1P1/3R4/P1P4P/3B2K1 w - - 0 1"]
```

Comment: Can you find it in any other system of notation?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's another puzzle from the password game/website.

Answer (score 2):

First, examine the position and ideas may start to come to mind. Notice that the Black King has no moves due to the pawn on f6 and that the White Rook on d3 has access to the h-file. The Knight on e7 guards the g6-square.

White plays **1. Qxh7+** to remove the h7 pawn. The King must capture (**1...Kxh7**) and is then without a shield or anywhere to run.

**2. Rh3#** gets it done.

```
[Title "Mate in Two"]
[FEN "r3n1rk/q3NQ1p/p2pbP2/1p4p1/1P1pP1P1/3R4/P1P4P/3B2K1 w - - 0 1"]

1. Qxh7+ Kxh7 2. Rh3# {Checkmate.} (1. Qxe6 {Even the alternative is quite winning.} 1...Nxf6 2. Qxf6+ Rg7 3. Nf5+− {White is winning.})
```